# Browser loads old bundle.js from Webpack

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I'm a React newbie attempting to learn how to integrate a Flask app with React. I'm finding that whenever I make changes to my React `.js` files, the changes are being recompiled in my `bundle.js` but not appear in my browser.

To replicate, clone the source code from [this Github repo](https://github.com/bonniee/react-flask). Follow the instructions to set up, and make sure to run `webpack --watch` and `python app.py` from a virtual environment. It should start up a simple web server accessible at `localhost:5000`.

You should get this screen when visiting on Chrome:
[image]

Next, go into your `Hello.js` file and make some random edits- for example, change `Hello World!` to `Hello everyone!`. From what I've learned, `webpack --watch` should take care of listening to changes and recompiling, which it does: if you go into `bundle.js` you'll see that the changes have been recompiled:

```
var Hello = _react2.default.createClass({
  displayName: 'Hello',
  render: function render() {
    return _react2.default.createElement(
      'h1',
      null,
      'Hello, everyone!'
    );
  }
});
```

However, when you refresh your browser, you'll get the same exact message (Hello World) as before. When I inspect the source `bundle.js` that Chrome is using, I find that it is STILL using my old code:[image].

My theory is that Chrome is using some sort of caching? But I have been playing around with this for about an hour and am unable to get my `bundle.js` to update.

What is causing my browser to load my `bundle.js` file?

**Edit:** I reloaded, and now the change has been applied to my browser screen. However, it seems like an exceptionally long time to refresh and update- at least 4-5 minutes. Any way to shorten this time frame?

Comment: You're getting the compile messages from `webpack --watch` though, right?

Comment: @CodyG. Yep, webpack appears to be working fine

Comment: Besides disabling cache as other answers also stated, you can also  try incognito mode on Chrome in addition to disabling cache to see if bundle.js is being reduced and/or being divided into chunks. This is also helps you identify if the problem is related to cache.

Comment: Alternatively, so you have options, if you hold the refresh button you can do a hard refresh that reloads the cache.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, chrome caches this file. It always has the same name.
You could prevent caching by opening dev tools and setting `Disable cache` flag in the Network tab.
[image]

But note that you need some sort of cache preventing approach for production, because your users will not have this flag set.
I suggest using md5 hash in bundle name.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate more what you mean by "cache preventing approach for production"? Once I've finished developing, my source files should be static, so it shouldn't matter if it's cached or not, right? I was only thinking about how this would make it difficult to debug during dev...

Comment: So what Bsalex is refering to is appending your bundle.js with a new name such as `bundle-AJE3XF.js` each time you build it so that when you release to your users that they are for sure not going to get a cached build. It's also known as cache busting. It's required when you make incompatible changes to your code and a user might still have a cached file on their computer.  (You don't want them to use your old code, but you also don't want them to not use a cache all of the time, so changing the file name gets around this.) Webpack has a feature to automatically do this and require the newfile

Answer (score 2):

Besides disabling cache in the inspector, you can hold down the Refresh icon and select the third option "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" to flush out cache.

Also, it sometimes helps to hit the URL to the script in the browser: 
`https://yourhost.com/bundle.js`

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome there is a setting to disable the cache, (F12 to open dev tools, go to the settings):

[image: Chrome Dev Tool Settings]

Alternatively you can shift+f5 to refresh, etc.